# Migrating Passwords with Different Encryptions (CubeCart to Prestashop)

Tags: php, prestashop, password-encryption

I'm moving customers from CubeCart to Prestashop and would like to keep customers existing customer passwords.

I have found a contribution on the Prestashop forums that seems to do what I'm in need of, but, it is for ZenCart/OScommerce to Prestashop.
Therefore there is a slight difference in passsword structure that I need help with, please see below:

**ZC/OSC**
Format: 1 column, 32 alphanumeric characters + colon + 2 alphanumeric characters salt.
E.g.
e56d64755f66a86996b54114bb4102bf:08

**CC**
Format: 2 columns, 32 alphanumeric characters + a seperate 6-digit random salt.
E.g.
password: e56d64755f66a86996b54114bb4102bf
salt: 7pZcAF

So I'd please like abit of help adapting the below code to work with the 2 column CC password/salt:

```
// == BEGIN ZEN-CART / OSCOMMERCE TO PRESTASHOP PASSWORD INTEGRATION ==
// == BY João Cunha - this.person@joaocunha.eti.br
// == @ 31/03/2012
// == USE AND MODIFY AT WILL
// == TESTED ON PRESTASHOP V1.4.7X
if (!$result) { //<- INVALID PRESTASHOP LOGIN, IT MAY BE A ZEN-CART / OSCOMMERCE     PASSWORD
//CHECK IF THE GIVEN EMAIL MATCHES A ROW IN OUR LEGACY TABLE AND RETRIEVES THE LEGACY     PASSWORD
$resultZC = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
SELECT `password`
FROM `zc_legacy_passwords`
WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'
AND `updated` = 0');

 if (!$resultZC)
return false; //<- EMAIL NOT FOUND IN NONE OF THE TABLES, SO IT IS AN INVALID LOGIN

//ENCRYPTS THE GIVEN PASSWORD IN ZEN-CART / OSCOMMERCE FORMAT
$salt = substr($resultZC['password'], strrpos($resultZC['password'],':')+1, 2);
$ZCpassword = md5($salt . $passwd) . ':' . $salt;

if ($ZCpassword != $resultZC['password'])
return false; //<- WRONG ZEN-CART/OSCOMMERCE PASSWORD GIVEN

//WE'LL UPDATE THE CUSTOMER TABLE WITH ITS PRESTASHOP ENCRYPTED PASSWORD...
Db::getInstance()->Execute('
                        UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_   .'customer`
                        SET `passwd` = \''.md5(pSQL(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd)).'\'
                        WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'');

//...AND FLAG IT AS UPDATED, SO THE NEXT TIME HE LOGS IN, HE WON'T ENTER THIS ROUTINE.
Db::getInstance()->Execute('
                UPDATE `zc_legacy_passwords`
                SET `updated` = 1
                WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'');

//USER IS AUTHENTICATED, OVERWRITE THE EMPTY $result VARIABLE
$result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
SELECT *
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_ .'customer`
WHERE `active` = 1
AND `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'
AND `deleted` = 0
AND `is_guest` = 0');
}
// == END ZEN-CART / OSCOMMERCE TO PRESTASHOP PASSWORD INTEGRATION
```

This code will also updates the old salted password to the new Prestashop password type.

Comment: Uhh don't you need the original passwords first? One doesn't simply reverse an md5 hash. Update your new code to use the same password checking and generating code that your old code uses because you can't do it otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I have the original encrypred passwords.  The code above updates the new code but in the Zen Cart / OScommerce format.  I need help modifying the above code to instead update the new code the the CubeCart (CC) code.

Comment: You need the original UNENCRYPTED passwords.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need the unencrypted passwords - wouldn't you just hash the encrypted ones and use these now twice-hashed passwords for saving/authenticating against?

Answer (score 0):

this not important because this just check password :

> SELECT `password` FROM `zc_legacy_passwords` WHERE `email` =
>   \''.pSQL($email).'\' AND `updated` = 0');

and then this code check the password in table database ZenCart/OScommerce you can remove or comment (just ignore)

> $salt = substr($resultZC['password'], strrpos($resultZC['password'],':')+1, 2);
>   $ZCpassword = md5($salt . $passwd) . ':' . $salt;
>
> if ($ZCpassword != $resultZC['password']) return false;

and this important because will store and modify password to prestashop (not need modif here)

> Db::getInstance()->Execute('
>   UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_   .'customer` SET `passwd` =
>   \''.md5(pSQL(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd)).'\' WHERE `email` =
>   \''.pSQL($email).'\'');

ignore this:

> Db::getInstance()->Execute(' UPDATE `zc_legacy_passwords` SET
>   `updated` = 1 WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'');

ignore this :

> $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow(' SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_
>   .'customer` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\' AND
>   `deleted` = 0 AND `is_guest` = 0');

so, the code will look like :

> if (!$result) {
>
> Db::getInstance()->Execute(' UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_   .'customer` SET
>
> `passwd` = \''.md5(pSQL(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd)).'\' WHERE `email` =
>
> \''.pSQL($email).'\'');
>
> }

Comment: Thanks hendrathings.

This works for updating the password, but it does not check the password through the old encryption method.

What I'd like to do is first check the password in the old encryption method (salt + password), then if it matches, update the password.

Comment: hemn, what version your cubecart? Im not sure for check if i dont know what use for encription md5 / sha1

Comment: try this : `if (hash('whirlpool', $salt.$value.$salt)) return false;` change `$value` to customer UNENCRYPTED passwords and `$salt` to your salt setting. if not set salt try `substr(str_pad(dechex(mt_rand()), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ), -8);` to create salt, this default in cubecart version 5.

Answer (score 0):

It is so hard, even impossible to migrate password with different encryption. So, maybe too late for your question, i think anyone wanna migrate passwords should try an available to move them automatically. This tool doesnt require you any tech skills without some simple clicks. [LitExtension](http://litextension.com/prestashop-migration-tools.html) is one of my suggestions. Of course you have to pay a little, but its not too much.